# Mapping Regex matches to original string

Tags: c#, regex

The following sentence

> I have a red car

Can be transformed to this string

> Pronoun Verb Determiner Adjective Noun

What I want is to find parts of the original sentence that are noun phrases (NP). A simple pattern for NP is (Determiner)*(Adjective)*(Noun) (where * means that the group may appear zero or more times). Actual regex is:

```
public static string Regex = "((?:Determiner.?)*(?:Adjective.?)*(?:Noun.?))";
```

Using the following code it is possible to extract all NPs:

```
        MatchCollection NPmatches = Regex.Matches(structure, NounPhrase.Regex); 
        foreach(Match match in NPmatches)
        {
            foreach (Capture NPcapture in match.Captures)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(NPcapture.Value.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Output would be:

> Determiner Adjective Noun

What I really need is the part of the original sentence corresponding to that structure (NP), in this case it would be

> a red car

I can figure out somehow where the regex match is located, and count number of words from there, but it is messy and error prone. It would be great if that could be done using some LINQ expression combined with regex, in order to keep in scope the source of the transformation. Any thoughs?

PS. A sentence is transformed to types using this code

```
RawSentence.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(i=>i.Type.ToString()).Aggregate((x,y) => x + " " + y);
```

Comment: Can't say I understand what you are asking. A match *does* return the matching part of the original statement. If you use a named group, you can even refer to the groups by name.

Comment: The issue here is that I want the corresponding part of my original sentence. The string I'm performing regex operations is *not* the original string, it is a transformed string. In this case my original sentence is "I have a red car". For this analysis I need to transform it to the following string: "Pronoun Verb Determiner Adjective Noun". When I find my NounPhrase I don't have a clear way of knowing which part of my original sentence corresponds to it ("a red car").

Comment: Not having the time to elaborate, but to give an idea about what I would do: you could use a second regex that groups each word of your non-transformed sentence seperated by space, then use capturing groups of the matches for the transformed sentence, not those non-capturing `(?:determiner.?)` and then use the groups of your existing Matches on the second regex.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? The regex and the desired output are unrelated. You try to capture single characters yet expect entire words. You specify named groups but work with raw captures. You are looking for ranges yet you only use the values of the captures

Comment: Another possibly better way would be to `tag` your original string in order to categorize the word types, that way you could use XML to extract specific grammatical elements `<det>a</det><adj>red</adj><noun>car</noun>`, also you could add nested grammatical categorization / tags, eg for subordinate clauses .

Comment: I'd keep a mapping between indexes of the beginning of words in the original string and the transformed string. Then, use the group indexes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need more than just a mapping from your original sentence to the words "Pronoun", "Verb", "Determiner", "Adjective", and "Noun". You did indicate that some parts of speech (i.e. your determiners, adjectives, and nouns) may occur zero or more times. If they appear more than once, then even if you did have a mapping from the original sentence down to your parts of speech, you wouldn't be able to get back to the original text because you would then have a one-to-many relationship. You would instead need to label your determiners, adjectives, and nouns uniquely, such as determiner1, determiner2, adjective1, noun1, noun2, noun3, etc. Once you have your unique mappings, you can go either direction with ease.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I ended up doing it in a similar way: transformed sentence would be `0Pronoun 1Verb 2Determiner 3Adjective 4Noun` Extracted NP: `2Determiner 3Adjective 4Noun`. Extracting numbers from this last string gives word indices in the original sentence: 2-3-4 -> 'a red car'.